# MySQL QUOTE() vs mysql_real_escape_string()?

Tags: c++, mysql, c

In MySQL, what are the differences between `QUOTE()` and `mysql_real_escape_string()`? From the MySQL documentation, I know the following:

**QUOTE()**

- Written into SQL query
- Escapes backslash, single quote, NUL, CTRL+Z
- Returns a single-quoted string
- Behavior relies on the MySQL server's character set

**mysql_real_escape_string()**

- Written in C/C++ before a query is executed, allowing the escaped string to be read/modified before submission
- Very inconvenient to use when compared to `QUOTE()`
- Escapes backslash, single quote, NUL, CTRL+Z, and **double quote, \n, and \r**
- Apparently adds more quotes to make characters easily readable in log files
- Behavior relies on the MySQL server's character set

Ignoring logs, is it useful to escape `\n` and `\r` characters? With these two functions, is there a difference in client/server function efficiency? `mysql_real_escape_string()` sounds useful if it's desirable for a developer to process the escaped string before it's entered into a query. However, does `QUOTE()` not provide the most secure and reliable method of escaping strings?

I wonder if I should use `QUOTE()` for all queries in all languages and forget escaping strings with language-specific functions.

---

- [QUOTE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_quote)
- [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html)
- [String Literals](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `QUOTE()` is meant to be used within SQL statements that construct other SQL statements. If you are outside of SQL, you should use `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

> [...] In a C program, you can use the `mysql_real_escape_string()` C API function to escape characters. [...] Within SQL statements that construct other SQL statements, you can use the `QUOTE()` function.

As explained at the bottom of [String Literals (MySQL Manual)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html).

Answer (score 0):

`QUOTE()` is already in the query, so it's just as easy to break out of as if you had put nothing there. `mysql_real_escape_string` is essential to make an arbitrary string safe to shove in a query.

The problem of the function name being unwieldly can be easily solved by using some kind of alias. I'm no C/C++ user, but doesn't it have macros you can use to essentially write whatever you want and it gets replaced with the long function name?

Comment: So `QUOTE()` is not injection-safe? When would `QUOTE()` be appropriate to use? I'm worried about functionality, not convenience. You're also correct in that C++ has macros.